# Check username JQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following ajax call

```
 $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "Utilities/CheckUsername.php",
                data: "un="+ un,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    if(data!=1)
                    {          
                    $('#mike').html(data);
                     return false; 
                    }                   
                }     
            });
```

I want the page to stay if the username is taken, else redirect to whats in the action attribute of the for.

Obviously this isn't working. But why? I would like to not use `preventdefault`, so that I could get a better understanding of where the problem and solution is.

EDIT:
The server code

```
<?php
        $seed = 'n48sma94r98';
        $email = $_POST['un'];
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','uml','uml','uml');
        if (!$mysqli) 
        { 
            printf("Can't connect to MySQL Server. Errorcode: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error()); 
            exit; 
        }
        $query = "Select User_Email as Email  from user2 where User_Email = AES_ENCRYPT('$email','$seed') ";
            $result = $mysqli->query($query);
            if($result->num_rows > 0)
            {    
             echo "1";
            }
            else
            {
            echo "2";
            }

?>
```

The entire form minus the meta:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="Resources/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#login").submit(function() {
        var un  = $('#username').val();       
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "Utilities/CheckUsername.php",
                data: "un="+ un,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    if(data!=1)
                    {          
                    $('#mike').html(data);
                     return false; 
                    }                   
                }     
            });
             }); 
             }); 
             </script>
</head>
<body>
      <form name="login" id="login" method="post" action="dsds.html">
        UserName<input type="text" name="username" id="username"value="">
        Password<input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="">
        Password Again<input type="text" name="passwordagain" id="passwordagain" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="NewClass" id="NewClass" value="true">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
     </form>
     <span id = "mike"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should probably add more of your code so we can understand what you are trying to do.  Is this being executed on form.submit()?

Comment: Also show some server side code, to show what responses are returned when a username (`un`?) was taken already.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you would write meaningful variable names. Also the echo 1 and echo 2 don't need quotes, however this is a terrible idea, you could return more meaningful messages, like usernameExists,usernameFound or usernameNotExists,usernameNotFound. Even if you are the only one working on this project, when you go around and ask for help peeps need to understand your code. It should read like sentences.

Comment: What is the value in `$('#mike')` after you click the login button?

Answer (score 2):

Some advice. Name your variables and methods. What is 'un' and 'data'? What do they contain?

Also what type of data is returned? String, HTML, XML, JSON?

If you want to redirect you can use `window.location = 'someURL';`

To send a form you can do this: `$('#form-id').submit();`

You could return more meaningful messages, like usernameExists,usernameFound or usernameNotExists,usernameNotFound. Even if you are the only one working on this project, when you go around and ask for help, peeps need to understand your code. It should read like sentences.

Comment: `window.location` without the `s`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use

```
if(data!=1)
```

to see of the username was taken or not?

Did you try to see the value of `data` using some sort of a debugger? (or even an `alert()`).

As I suppose you are not sending a `1` from the server when the username is already taken...

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `OK` as response indicator (or whatever you call that). If the response (your `data`) starts with `OK` it's positive, otherwise the entire message is the error:

In Javascript:

```
success: function(response) {
    if ( 'OK' == response.substr(0, 2) ) {
        // Okay, so show something green or do nothing
        var message = response.substr(2); // Everything after "OK"
    }
    else {
        // Not okay, so show something red or redirect
        var goto = response;
        // The entire response message `response` is the target destination
        // If you don't want PHP to define the redirect location, just hard code it right here
        window.location = goto;
    }
}
```

And in PHP:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$usernameExists = $result->num_rows > 0; // A nice boolean

exit( $usernameExists ? '/error.html' : 'OKThis username is fine' );
```

**PS**. The `return false` in the `success` function does nothing. You can omit that.

**edit**
Without changing the PHP:

```
success: function(response) {
  if ( '1' !== response ) {
    window.location = 'error.html';
  }
}
```

Since `response` is a string, I'd check for that (and not a number). And it never hurts to check for identicallity (`===`) instead of equality (`==`).

Comment: The data variable is showing a 2 if the username does not exists and a 1 if it doesnt. (The php works) If it's a 1 I want to redirect to another page, if its a 2 , They have to try another username. Thats what I need help with.